# Short story about a bunch of scientists visiting a radioactive island

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I don't remember much about this short story. All I remember is my friend telling me it around 6 years ago. What I do remember is scientists visit a radioactive island where missiles had been sent and was generally covered in radioactive waste. There they met a bunch of people who couldn't have feasibly survived all the radiation. This is as much as I remember. I think there was also something to do with aliens.

Comment: Any chance this was a Fallout fanfic?